# Content Builder - Updating template based emails after a template Change is Duplicating Content Blocks

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I'm seeing some of my content blocks in template based emails duplicate when clicking 'update from template' after making changes at the template level. Example - I might have a single HTML block in the template.  When I make a change to the template (but still only have 1 HTML block) and then update the email to pull in the template level changes, the email will now have two instances of that same HTML block.  I'm seeing this very regularly.  Is this a known issue?  Anyone figured out a way to fix this? (short of just deleting the duplicate block in the template based email?)

Comment: It seems to be a know issue. I've personnaly run into this problem several times. I just delete the duplicate block as you've said ..

Comment: If you have "block" in the template "LOCK" it to disable the editing when you use the template. Locked content do not create duplicate when you click "update from template". Obviously you can't edit "locked" content at email level.
If you edit or simply "click" over a block present in the template cause the duplication when you try to update the template.